# How to create nested dictionary from fs with names of nodes from the file content?

Tags: python, algorithm, file, recursion

I need to go into directory and look - is there any file with .txt extension, and if yes - extract content of this file and replace name of the current directory with this content. After that move forward into subdirectories and do the same.

E.g.:

On input:

```
directory
--name.txt
--subdir
----name.txt
--subdir2
----name.txt
----subdir3
-------name.txt
```

On output

```
{'name': 'directory/name.txt', 
'content': 'Name 1', 'descendent': 
       [{'name': 'directory/subdir/name.txt', 
       'content': 'Name 2', 
       'descendent': None}, 
        {'name': 'directory/subdir2/name.txt', 
         'content': 'Name 3', 
         'descendent': 
                [{'name': 'directory/subdir2/subdir3/name.txt', 
                'content': 'Name 4', 
                'descendent': None}]}]}
```

I wrote simple realization, but something goes wrong with it:

```
__author__ = 'ivanov'

import sys
import os
from os.path import isfile
import json

def readFile(filename):
    f = open(filename, 'r')
    res = f.read()
    f.close()
    return res

try:
    myname = sys.argv[1]
except Exception, e:
    print "usage : python [listfile.py] [foldername]"
    exit(1)

def getName(myname):
    if isfile(myname):
        if myname.split("/")[-1].endswith(".txt"):
            f = open(myname, 'r')
            res = f.read()
            f.close()
            return myname
    else:
        for i in os.listdir(myname):
            if isfile(os.path.join(myname, i)):
                return {"name": os.path.join(myname, i), "content": getName(os.path.join(myname, i))}
            else:
                return getName(os.path.join(myname, i))

file_folder_dict = getName(myname)

print file_folder_dict
```

How to improve it in my case?

Comment: What about os.walk()?

Comment: see os.walk: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk

Comment: What  'goes wrong with it'?

Answer (score 0):

According to you example output, it seems that you assume there is only one txt file inside a certain directory, and there might be multiple subdirectories. Here is the code using recursion under this assumption. The argument to getname() should be a path of a directory.

```
import sys
import os
import json

def readfile(filepath):
    f = open(filepath)
    res = f.read()
    f.close()
    return res.strip()

def getname(dirpath):
    onlyfile = [entry for entry in os.listdir(dirpath) \
            if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dirpath, entry)) \
            and entry.endswith(".txt")][0]
    onlyfilename = os.path.join(dirpath, onlyfile)

    decendent = []
    for entry in os.listdir(dirpath):
        entrypath = os.path.join(dirpath, entry)
        if os.path.isfile(entrypath):
            # we have handled this one, i.e. 'onlyfile'
            continue
        decendent.append(getname(entrypath))

    if len(decendent) == 0:
        decendent = None

    return {'name': onlyfilename,
            'content': readfile(onlyfilename),
            'decendent': decendent}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    dirpath = sys.argv[1]
    result = getname(dirpath)
    print json.dumps(result, indent=4)
```

And here is the output for the example directory structure:

```
$ python xx.py directory
{
    "content": "Name 1", 
    "name": "directory/name.txt", 
    "decendent": [
         {
            "content": "Name 2", 
            "name": "directory/subdir/name.txt", 
            "decendent": null
        }, 
        {
            "content": "Name 3", 
            "name": "directory/subdir2/name.txt", 
            "decendent": [
                {
                    "content": "Name 4", 
                    "name": "directory/subdir2/subdir3/name.txt", 
                    "decendent": null
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```